# Mapeamento do controller para o domain model

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, mvc, arquitetura-de-software

Temos as seguintes situações em geral, considere objetos maiores que o exemplo.

**Situação 1**
Podemos ter uma request que tem todos os parâmetros do account;
`{"id":"1";"name":"test","some":"xxx".............}` e os outros campos.

**Situação 2**
Podemos ter uma request que tem alguns parâmetros do account, por exemplo no caso de um update;
`{"id":"1";"name":"testUpdated"}`

**Situação 3**
Podemos ter uma request que tem alguns parâmetros do account, como id mais tem outros como usuário junto;
`{"id":"1";"user":"xxx","service":"yyy"}` nesse caso cada pedaço da request vai virar um objeto.

Exemplo de Dominio

```
public class Account {    
    private Long id;
    private String name ;
    private String some ;    
}
```

Vejo algumas opções;

1 - Posso receber no controller esse AccountForm e setar as propriedades dele no objeto Account e outros se nescesasrio NO CONTROLLER;

```
+ atende as situações 1, 2 e 3 
+ separa a requisçao do objeto de dominio 
- polui o controller com codigo de conversao 
- controller fica cheio de setters.. se for uma classe maior como um objeto grande como um pedido fica bem confuso. 

controller(AccountForm from){
    Account account = new Account()
    account.setNome=form.getNome();
    account.setSome=form.getSome();
    Other outher = new Other();
    other.setSome(form.getSome());
}
```

2 - Posso receber no controller esse AccountRequest ter um metodo nele mesmo como `AccountRequest.getAccount()` para devolver um model mapeado, nesse caso o mapeamento fica no proprio objeto de Request.

```
+ separa a requisçao do objeto de dominio 
+ encapsula a conversao em um lugar de facil acesso. 
+ atende situacao1 situacao2 e situacao3; 
+ um objeto burro que so tem os parametros da requisçao tem alguma funcionalidade; 
- objeto de request tem duas responsabilidades representar a requisiçao e mapear para um model valido.

controller(AccountForm accountRequest){
   Account account = accountRequest.getAccount();
   Outher outher = accountRequest.getOther();
}
```

3 - Posso receber Account direto no controller onde ficara cheia de nulos.

```
+ elimino objeto de request 
+ alta simplicidade 
- atende apenas a situacao1 situacao2 , por que request pode ter informações sobre vários objetos... o que não funcionaria. 
- forte acoplamento.

controller(Account account){
    account.someMethod();
}
```

4 - Externalizar esse mapeamento dos parametros da requisição para outro objeto mapeador por request.

```
+ isola logica do mapeamento 
- complexidade ate para casos mais simples se usado como padrão para tudo por exemplo um find por id.
- mais uma classe para cada request;
```

No caso de APi que tenha resposta fica pior ainda mais 2 classes. 
falando em termos de request de response....

```
request | mapper | model | mapper | response 
AccountRequest, AccountRequestMapper,Account,AccountResponseMapper,AccountResponse........
```

Estou fazendo testes mais o Hibrido da opção 3 para casos simples(find por id ou updates).... com a opção 2 por exemplo para casos mais complexos... parece o ideal pelo que estou vendo, espero que com a opiniao de voces fique mais claro.. o que poderia ser melhor, porém na abordagem hibrida, o problema é que voce não tem o famoso "PADRAO" e tem que pensar em como fazer a cada caso,e vejo resistência em adotar algo assim. 
O ruim do PADRAO é que gera arquitetura mostro para fazer um find por exemplo.

O que vocês usam /O que seria ideal/ O que fica expressivo e de facil manutenção?

Comment: Imagine o trabalho que dá para responder e te ajudar em algo que você precisa. Se você não pode se esforçar, porque pessoas aleatórias na internet que nada ganham para isto devem se esforçar?

Comment: Deveria sintetizar ao máximo a pergunta. Isso não é uma pergunta é uma tese!...Quanto mais simples for a pergunta mais rápido terá a resposta, depois pode ir melhorando, lapidando as respostas

Comment: Bom a pergunta é simples e é sobre design e arquitetura de codigo, gostaria de ouvir opniões basedas em experiencia,qualquer pessoa que não seja junior ja teve que optar por alguma destas em qualquer aplicação web. o caso pelo que estou vendo é que so tem jr por aqui e estao querendo ganhar pontos... por causa de desse gamification por isso odeio esse modelo de perguntas e resposta, so estava testando essa ferramenta para quem não acredita olha o nivel das respostas para a mesma pergunta no guj http://www.guj.com.br/java/308252-mapeamento-do-controller-para-o-domain-model#1639927

Comment: Acho que há uma confusão de várias coisas aqui. O problema da sua pergunta não é nem o benefício que ela pode trazer, mas que ela *pode* potencialmente provocar alguma discussão, que é uma das premissas que o site tenta evitar. De fato, o correto é levá-la para um fórum ou um lugar onde a discussão seja livre (como o caso do GUJ). Peço desculpas se o site não atende ao seu propósito.